# Need to change the Context.Xml file

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a context.xml file that contains some xml content. I need to change the value of bean dynamically. I have a json that contain the value of the bean, I need to set that value in that bean property using java?

my context.xml file

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="xmlbeansMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xmlbeansMarshaller" />
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="https://www.google.com" />
    </bean>
```

I need to change the value of defaultUri dynamically using java?

Answer (score 0):

you can always `override` the value in java after setting in bean. Lets say your `defaultUri` is set to `"https://www.google.com"`. Then using java you might some method like `setDefaultUri()` where you can set it with a new value.
Other option is donot set it in the bean, just do it in java.